# How can I use @solana/spl-token's createMint() and mintTo() functions with solana wallet adapter?

Tags: spl-token, solana-wallet-adapter

I am trying to create a front end for minting and transferring tokens to accounts, and the @solana/spl-token library demands a private key for their functions. Is there a way to use solana wallet adapter instead?

Comment: Could you share some code of what you tried?

Comment: @C.OG Yeah sorry, I forgot. But the answer by vicyyn is pretty much the code I had. Thanks for the response tho!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**in your frontend**

```
    const wallet = useAnchorWallet()
    const payer = (wallet as NodeWallet).payer
```

**then**

```
    const mint = await splToken.createMint(program.provider.connection, payer, payer.publicKey, null, 0);

    ata_account = await splToken.createAssociatedTokenAccount(
      program.provider.connection,
      payer,
      mint,
      payer.publicKey,
    );

    await splToken.mintTo(
      program.provider.connection,
      payer,
      mint,
      ata_account,
      payer.publicKey,
      1,
    );
```

Comment: Hey, what is the user_nft_account variable you passed in? Is it just the address of the ata_account or the user?

Comment: yeah that should be ata_account. just forgot to change the name